# C# Updating Table Using Gridview and a Link Button

Tags: c#, sql, linq, gridview, sql-update

I have a table named "PurchaseOrders" and in that table there are 2 columns I want to update, "Closed" and "Notes". Basically I have a link button that is called "Force Close" and what this is suppose to do is grab the PurchaseOrderID(hidden field on the gridview) from the gridview then use it to update those 2 columns on the table so that, the current purchase order is closed. I just don't know how to do the update in the code behind button click event. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the mark up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkyVB.png

Comment: I'm wondering if the project you're working on has any other code that you could reference. You first need to handle click event on the button and then run a sql query to update data in table just the way other sql queries in your project might be running. The PurchaseOrderID can be grabbed by writing code inside the buttonClick event handler that you would create.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. I'm just having troubles with the coding side of things. Could you give a basic code example of how to approach this?

Comment: Can you show us the layout? Is a 'Force Close' button there in each row of the GridView? If you could post the markup, that might help you in getting more precise answers.

Comment: I've added the mark up. No, the "Force Close" button is a link button that is not in the gridview.